# does Ruby on Rails have a way to use jQuery rather than Prototype under-the-bonnet for its ajax view helpers? (e.g. "link_to_remote")

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

Does Ruby on Rails have a way to use jQuery rather than Prototype under-the-bonnet for its ajax view helpers?  (e.g. "link_to_remote")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[jRails](http://github.com/aaronchi/jrails) works for Rails 2, overriding various functions to get the job done. However, Rails 3 allows you to entirely replace the Prototype driver with [a jQuery driver](http://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs) of equal precedence.

If you haven't started the project yet, you may want to consider using Rails 3, as the solution is much more complete. That is, if other plugins you need are compatible - see [RailsPlugins.org](http://railsplugins.org/).

Comment: Which one? jRails? I've used it well without a hitch, and it's relatively well-known in the Rails community. No match for the Rails 3 system, but as good at it got until then.

Comment: Rails 3 is pretty darn solid. All that's missing is gem, plugin support, which is actively being worked on.

Answer (score 0):

In Rails 2.x you might be interested in jRails: http://github.com/aaronchi/jrails

Answer (score 0):

In Rails 2 I had no luck with jrails (which seems abandoned at this point). I did get `link_to_remote` to work with this Prototype-to-Jquery translation in JavaScript:

```
// Doing the Prototypey things with jQuery instead.
window.Ajax = {
  Updater: function (update_id, request_uri, settings) {
    $.ajax({
      url: request_uri + "?" + settings.parameters,
      dataType: "html",
      timeout: 5000,
      async: settings.asynchronous,
      error: function() {
        console.warn("Error talking to server.");
      },
      success: function(data) {
        $("#"+update_id).html(data);
      }
    });
  }
};
```

(If you go this route you'll need similar translations for any other helpers you use.)